# actualiza solo la primer pagina del Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente inconveniente en un modal que tiene datos de una tabla mysql realizo un calculo, coloco un valor en un input y en un boton realiza la función de multiplicar y restar cada valor de una columna por el valor del input  y coloca el resultado en la columna de al lado . el problema es que el datatable esta paginada cada 10 registros y no me toma la segunda pagina el calculo es decir no llena la columna cantidad de unidades en la pagina 2 . Adjunto  el codigo de la función  y la imagen del modal .Muchas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//codigo de la función javascrpit donde multiplica el valor del input x columna //"cantidad" y coloca el resultado en columna "cantidad de unidades"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function asignar() {
  var dato1 =  document.getElementById("canti").value;
  if(dato1.trim().length == 0 ){
   alertify.alert("Atención","Por favor ingrese datos para cantidad");
   return false;

  }else{
  $('#sampleTable2 >tbody >tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    var stock = $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var cant = $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text();
    $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').html (stock-(cant*dato1));
     });
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Agrega la declaracion del datatable.

Comment: Perdón No entiendo?

Comment: Agrege var table = $('#sampleTable2').DataTable(); y luego $('table >tbody >tr').each(function(i, tr) {.... Pero no funciona

Comment: Agrega el codigo donde declaras el datatable.

Comment: Necesitas llamar a tu funcion en `drawCallback` de datatables.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Comment: Hola alanfcm, tu me ayudaste con el codigo del calculo más temprano. Gracias  y ahora descubri este inconveniente.

Comment: Hola  alanfcm, tu me ayudaste con el código del calculo más temprano. Gracias pero ahora encontre este inconveniente...

Comment: El problema es el metodo que usas para calcular debes o quitar el paginado para que este metodo funcione o utilizar la api de datatable para calcular